# Folding a non-rectangular shape into a rectangle of uniform thickness

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, examples, origami-folding

I think the following might be an interesting subproblem of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/365675/108884):

> **Question:** For an odd number $n\ge 3$, is there a *non-rectangular* but still *convex* shape of area $A=1$, that can be folded (no tearing) into a *rectangle* of area $1/n$ of uniform thickness, that is, the resulting rectangle has $n$ layers of paper everywhere?

---

**Why these restriction?**

It is easy for every $n$ when dropping convexity (see [my answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/365678/108884)).

It is also easy for $n=2$ (see the parallelogram below), and once you have a rectangle, you can get any multiple of $n$ too. This is why I ask for *odd* $n$.

[image]

It is also easy if the result does not have to be a rectangle:
a circular disc admits an $n$-layer folding for all $n$, and for each fixed $n$ there is a polygonal shape admitting an $n$-layer folding (again, see [my answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/365678/108884)).
Here is a solution for $n=3$:

[image]

But as far as I can tell, the resulting triangle cannot be made into a 9-layer folding.
This would be possible if the result would have been a rectangle.

In particular, I have no solution to my questions for $n=3$, nor an argument why it should not be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also have no solution for $n=3$, but I have solutions for every $n > 3$. The constructions are sketched below, for each of them we fold along all grid lines; folding along the red lines first has helped me understand that this really gives a uniform cover of the unit square. The number of layers is equal to the area of the polygon.

[image]

Constructions for multiples of $3$ can be obtained by further folding the rectangles obtained from the constructions for their other prime divisors or (for powers of $3$) from the construction for $n=9$.